# Extention to enable the use of Multiple proxies on multiple Firefox tabs

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, proxies

I need to develop a Firefox extension that will do the following: 
Use multiple proxies at the same time on different tabs
Integrate the extension with my application so that it can pull The list of proxies through API.
Open multiple email accounts from the same ISP (Gmail/yahoo)

I would provide the API endpoint for the list of proxies or whatever other info is requested.
From my application I will also associate a certain number of emails/user ids to the list of proxies. So that when I click on the particular userid’s “open email in new tab” widget it will open a new Firefox tab with the email login page using the proxy associated to that email id.

Any ideas if this is even possible to do?
I guess I could create profiles on the fly through that extension and enter the info dynamically.
Thanks a lot guys!!

Comment: Hi there were you able to find out a way

Comment: Apparently no one answered this question....

Comment: Yeah it's a tricky one. It doesn't seem like we can do it on a per tab basis. When they were designing the proxy api for webextensions I brought to their attention this question. They didn't acknowledge that email, but hopefully they'll have something. What's your email I'll forward you that email so you can get involved, mine is noitidart@gmailc.om